# Prove expression involving $\log$ has no solution on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory

Is there a way to prove:

$m = \log(k) ( m' \log(k+1)  +  t)$

has no solution when $m, m', t \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}, k>1$?

I am trying to establish a proof based on transcendency of $\log{k}$ but any other approach is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\log(k)$ and $\log(k+1)$ aren't rational multiples of one another, [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) asserts that the field

$$ \mathbb{Q}(\log(k), \log(k+1), e^{\log(k)}, e^{\log(k+1)}) 
= \mathbb{Q}(\log(k), \log(k+1))$$

must have transcendence degree 2 or greater. Thus, there is no polynomial relation with rational coefficients relating $\log(k)$ and $\log(k+1)$.

Of course, Schanuel's conjecture is still a conjecture, but actual theorems are hard to come by in this subject. I don't know if you'll be able to massage your actual problem into any of the forms to which existing theorems apply.

Comment: Thank you. Really useful.  I wonder if there is way to slice this, or the original problem in such a way a valid theorem could be used. My original expression is: $\sin( \phi_1 +\frac{2\pi m}{\log{k}}) =  \sin( \phi_1 +\frac{2\pi m'}{\log{(k+1)}})$ I need to show this expression does not hold for all $k>1 \in \mathbb{N}$ where $m, m' \in \mathbb{Z}$. Or in other words there is $k$  for which it does not hold.